# Not being able to animate TranslateTransform.XProperty with code

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a method that enables me to animate objects that have to do with a DoubleAnimation:

```
public void animDouble(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty property, double to, TimeSpan duration, double? from = null, TimeSpan? beginTime = null, IEasingFunction e = null)
{

    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.To = to;

    if (beginTime == null)
        beginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

    if (from != null)
        animation.From = from;


    animation.BeginTime = beginTime;
    animation.Duration = duration;


    if (e != null)
        animation.EasingFunction = e;

    //start animating
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, target);  // what object will be animated?
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(property)); // what property will be animated
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(animation);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

so if I have a boarder called br1 for example and I want to animate it's height I will call the method as:

```
animDouble(br1, FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, 150, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

if I want to animate it's width I will do:

```
animDouble(br1, FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, 150, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

I could also animate it's visibility with the same method.

for some reason I am not able to animate its x property in order to translate it along the x axis or y-axis. When I call the method as:

```
a.animDouble(br1, TranslateTransform.XProperty, 150, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

the boarder does not animates. I don't get any errors aether.

Comment: Please don't just slap "C#" into your titles. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i would have expected an error, well, anyway, the `Border` owns no such property, if you want to move your control you need to set the `RenderTransform` or `LayoutTransform` of the border to a `TranslateTransform`, then you can pass the transform itself into the method as target.

(*The whole storyboard is awfully redundant as you only have one animation, you can just call `BeginAnimation` on the target itself*)

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with registering the name. I found a link in [here](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/03/wpf-doubleanimationusingkeyframes-using.html)

I don't know what the method registerName does but I guess I needed it. from the page I managed to get the basic animations. I where not able to animate two things at once SOMETIMES. [if you are interested in seeing the method take a look tat this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999839/not-able-to-animate-two-animations-at-the-same-time-on-code-behind). I think it is a prety nice class that will enable to create animations with code. copy the namespace to visual studio and copy the first example that I posted so that you can see how it works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with it and you seem to be quite confused about how **[animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)** work...